# "x and y must be the same size" issues in python, histogram graph and scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, histogram, scatter-plot

My code does not load because the information mentioned below appears. Remembering that my `ppthdf` variable is an excel file with 1 column and 100000 lines.  Could you at least guess what I'm wrong?

Code:

```
p = np.arange(0.001, 100000, 0.01)
counts, bins = np.histogram(ppthdf['PPth'], density=True)   
plt.scatter(p, counts, s=100, c='red')
plt.show()
```

Problem:

> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

(Actually the graph above is for plotting together with a histogram, but my histogram works, I just can't put dots on the histogram, which is the reason for the code above.)

Comment: This must be because the size of `p` and `counts` is not the same to plot the points. You probably want to make sure the number of `p` you are generating equals the size of `counts`.

Comment: Try to print their shapes by `print(counts.shape, p.shape)`, and you'll find out why. Chances are, `counts` has only 10 rows, whereas your p has 10000000 rows.

Are your trying to plot the histogram?

Comment: Yes I am, I want to plot the histogram but with the points at the top of each bin (a mixture of scatter and histo to visualize a function).

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays `p` and `counts` are different sizes.
The size of your `p` array is 10,000,000.
The size of `counts` is 100,000.

You should just do:

```
p = np.arange(0,100000,1)
```

Comment: Unsuccessfully. :( 
But thanks for trying to help me!